# Thread Stop with Jbutton (Java)

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jbutton, interrupt

I want to make an easy app. But I want to stop thread with a button. This code doesn't work. I saw all web sites like this way. I don't understand why not working.
Thread is starting with a `btnStart`.
`btnStop` isn't working. I wrote stopThread() function for stopping.
Which how this can do another way? Any idea?

```
private volatile boolean isRunning;
============== 
    private void stopThread() {
        isRunning=false;
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
============== 

    private final void runThread() {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {

                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                         Random r = new Random();
                         islemler[0] = "+";
                         islemler[1] = "-";
                         islemler[2] = "*";
                         islemler[3] = "/";

                         for (int i = 0; i <10; i++) {
                             islem1 = islemler[r.nextInt(4)];
                             islem2 = islemler[r.nextInt(4)];
                             islem3 = islemler[r.nextInt(4)];
                             islem4 = islemler[r.nextInt(4)];
                             txt1.setText("1"+islem1+"1");
                             txt2.setText("1"+islem2+"1");
                             txt3.setText("1"+islem3+"1");
                             txt4.setText("1"+islem4+"1");
                             Thread.sleep(150);
                             Thread.sleep(50);
                         }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }.start();
    }
==============
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                isRunning=true;
                runThread();
          **This part is working**
            }
        });
==============

btnStop = new JButton("Stop");
        btnStop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                stopThread();
         **But this part is not working. Can you help??**
            }
        });
```

Comment: Corrected formatting.

Comment: `while (isRunning && !isInterrupted())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

You have two threads open, possibly three if you have one set aside for the ui.

The first thread is the one the program launches on, and the second would be where you creating the random object and for-loop. When you are calling "stop thread" you are doing so from either the main thread or the third thread for the ui.

This means that

```
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
```

is not closing the correct thread.

### The Solution

For a solution to this problem, look at this [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-a-thread-can-interrupt-an-another-thread-in-java/) article which suggests storing threads as a variable and then you can reliably call the interrupt method on it.